# Reason for exponentially(?) decreasing atomic radius

Tags: atomic-physics, elements

Attached is a graph depicting atomic radius size across the first 20 elements. Why does the radius decrease in size when going from left to right across a period, and why is the decrease exponential, and not the same increment each time?[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Woodman: Suggestion to the question (v4): Can you cook up a crude toy model that could explain some of the features of the graphs?

Comment: What makes you think it's exponential? Just because it's convex? If so, does your observation remain once you include the transition metals into the reckoning?

Comment: Well obviously it's not totally exponential, however within the first two periods  it    appears to be, I was just describing the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cycles of rise/fall you see are a reason the periodic table is called ... periodic.

At the core of atoms is a nucleus, which attracts (because it has
a positive charge) negative charges, electrons.   Electrons can only be stable for
extended times when they are in one of the allowed orbitals, and...
for H and He, with one or two electrons, the lowest energy cost is the 1S orbital.   Any electrons in higher orbitals will eventually 
emit energy and decay to 1S.

He (having two positive charges) pulls its electrons to a nearer
distance than H (having only one).

Li through Ne, however, have to put electrons 3 and up into
unfilled spaces, of which the 1S orbital has none.  2S or 2P orbitals (two allowed in 2S, six allowed in 2P) are the lowest available.  It isn't exactly exponential, but the higher atomic number within the shell means a higher positive nuclear charge, and thus a smaller orbit, modulated by the repulsion of the electrons... so with
a crowded 2S and 2P shell, the size creeps up.

These rules can be related to quantum mechanical principles,
and to a lot of chemistry and other phenomena.   Radius is
only the beginning of what a periodic table can illuminate.